# Simultaneous multiple perturbations in Markov chain Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-chain, metropolis-hastings

I'm coding a **McMC** algorithm for geophysical applications.

Using the Metropolis–Hastings scheme to accept/reject the proposed models is something that I thought I understood completely, but I don't. To be clear:
normally you have a current model $m$, you perturb one parameter (in my case velocity $v_i$), and in this way you get a trial model $m'$.

The acceptance probability for such a perturbation is:

$$\alpha(m'|m)=min\left[ 1, \frac{p(m')}{p(m)} \cdot \frac{p(d|m')}{p(d|m)} \cdot \frac{q(m|m')}{q(m|m)} \cdot |J|\right]$$

Where $p(m)$ are the priors, $p(d|m)$ are the likelihoods, $q(m|m')$ are the proposals, and $J$ the Jacobian.

So assuming that the priors are symmetric, and the Jacobian is 1, I remain with:

$$\alpha(m'|m)=min\left[ 1,\frac{p(d|m')}{p(d|m)} \cdot \frac{q(m|m')}{q(m|m)} \right]$$

The likelihood ratio is not a problem, so now I want to deal only with the proposal ratio:

Supposing that the way I make a perturbation is choosing one parameter, and perturb it with Gaussian probability, so that the new velocity value will be $$v'_i=v_i + u \cdot \sigma$$ ($u$ is normal distributed with mean = 0 and var. = 1)
This perturbation can be described by a proposal in the form:

$$q(v'|v)= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \exp \left[- \frac{(v'-v)^2}{2 \sigma ^2} \right]$$

It's easy to see that for this kind of perturbation the proposals are symmetric, so the acceptance probability is just the ratio of the likelihoods.

**Questions:**

1. If instead of perturbing one parameter, I want to change 3 of them at the same time, what happens to my proposals, and so to my acceptance probability $\alpha$? How should I compute them? ($v_1, v_2, v_3$ are not correlated.)
2. If I want to include some deterministic constraints because I know that the 3 parameters I want to change are correlated, i.e. if I increase $v_1$ of $v_p$, then I want to decrease $v_2$ and $v_3$ of $v_p / 3$ (a sort of compensation)...how am I supposed to come up with a representation of the proposal?